# Editar ou adicionar nova resposta?

Tags: debate, respostas

Eu respondi uma pergunta no SOPT, que parece ter agradado, e já até ganhei uns pontos com ela... entretanto achei uma outra forma de fazer o que o OP pediu, e agora queria expor esta alternativa.

A nova solução é diferente da anterior... as duas são técnicas diferentes de uso de CSS. Eu diria que ambas são diferentes de fato, mas não classificaria como "muito diferentes" por usarem o mesmo recurso: CSS.

O que fazer?

- Editar a minha resposta, indicando a nova alternativa de solucionar o problema
- Adicionar uma nova resposta (uma vez fiz isso no SOEN, e alguns usuários reclamaram... mesmo a resposta sendo radicalmente diferente)